# Send email in background stop working for security reason

Tags: android, email, gmail

I have an Android application that sending a reset password for these who forgot their password. it all went well..but now i see that when a user ( i have tested it myself) trying to send from the application (he - click "send" . i am - sending him an email in background), goole prevent it(the user not getting any email) and sent to my email - 
"Someone used your password to try to get into your Google account , myemail@gmail.com , using an application such as an email client or mobile device .

(for example)Details:
Friday , April 22, 2016 5:51 ( New Zealand Time ( Winter ) )
Auckland , New Zealand *

We strongly recommend that you use a secure application , such as Gmail to access your account . All applications created by Google to meet these security standards . Using less secure apps may make the bill vulnerable . Learn more.
Google stopped this entry experience , but you should check the most recently used devices ."

so...this is strange ...google suddenly recognize my application code as malicious...or there is a way to upgrade my app to be more secure ? i m really confused..

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the Google Account Security settings and not by Android.

You have two options to solve this:

1. Enable the "Allow less secure apps" option in the [Sign-in & security settings](https://myaccount.google.com/security). This will enable the old email/password authentication mechanism for your account. This option is **NOT RECOMMENDED!**
2. The recommended method is to create a special application password. About how to do this see [the Google documentation](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) (you need also to enable 2-step verification in order to be able to create an app password)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i allready did number 1..but it didnt solve the problem. Anyway i have realized that it happen only in samsunsg 6....with android 6.0.1. It didnt happen with lg with android 6.0...